# Uploading audio data from a web page to a server

Tags: javascript, php, audio, xmlhttprequest, html5-audio

I am trying to upload audio data from a web page to a server and find it more difficult than it should be.

Here is my test page, it has a button and when it is clicked, a voice recording of 5 seconds starts, then it is played back and finally the sound data should be uploaded to the server.

The voice recording and play back parts are working fine.
The upload to the server is not completely working.

The code I have is totally visible below. I put the whole file (called "GetAudio.php") on purpose, so anyone can easily copy-paste it to try.

Here is what goes wrong: the file created on the server called "Audio.data", contains 4 characters, namely:

```
blob
```

This is not what I want. I want the file to contain the actual sound data that has been recorded locally. Can someone tell me where my code is missing some important thing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Record&Upload Trial</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h2>Five seconds voice record and upload.</h2>
    <p>
        <button id=startRecord><h3>Start the voice recording</h3></button><br/>
        <audio id="player" controls></audio>
        <p id="XMLH"></p>
    </p>
</div>

<?php
// Server side code:
if ($_POST['AudioData']) {
    $myfile = fopen("Audio.data", "w");
    fwrite($myfile, $_POST['AudioData']);
    fclose($myfile);
}
?>

<script>
startRecord.onclick = e => {
  startRecord.disabled = true;
  audioChunks = [];
  rec.start();
  setTimeout(() => {
    rec.stop();
    startRecord.disabled = false;
  }, 5000);
}

  var player = document.getElementById('player');

  var handleSuccess = function(stream) {
    rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    rec.ondataavailable = e => {
        audioChunks.push(e.data);
        if (rec.state == "inactive") {
            let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'});
            player.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            player.controls=true;
            player.autoplay=true;

            // The code below intends to upload the sound file to the server.
            // But it is partly (or completely) wrong and does not work.
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            var params = 'AudioData=blob';
            xhr.open('POST', 'GetAudio.php', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.send(params);
        }
    }
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
      .then(handleSuccess);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `var params = 'AudioData=blob';` into `var params = 'AudioData=' + blob;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it does not work. I tried and the result is a 13 characters file. It contains : "[object Blob]".

Comment: Take a look at [MDN's "Sending binary data"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#Sending_binary_data) tutorial.

Comment: I think I had seen it before and did not find it particularly helpful. Reading it again made me realize I could follow the idea of changing my blob to an array of bytes, but even after I figure out the right way to do that. How should I then modify the server part? There is no 'AudioData' field name left as in a normal form. I am in an unknown area here.